# What's wrong with non-drinkable water in public toilets?

Tags: health, health-risk

I often go into a public toilet, and over the taps is a sign saying "Do not drink this water" owtte. I have occasionally drunk water from non-drinkable taps, and needless to say I didn't die. What's the risk, and what's wrong with water that you aren't supposed to drink?

Answer (score 3):

It could be marked as non-potable for a variety of reasons. It could be [reclaimed water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reclaimed_water), as defined:

> water that is not used for drinking, but is safe to use for irrigation
>   or industrial purposes.

I worked in a building that marked a lot of sources as non-potable because the pipes were leeching minerals into the water that were higher than what was considered safe for human consumption. In that building the water fountains were pulled and filtration systems were put into the lounge and kitchen areas.

Specifically speaking, the risk is:

a) You are ingesting pathogens via untreated water.

b) You are ingesting chemicals, particularly heavy metals, in greater concentrations than are considered safe.

In the first case you might get away with it every now and then, in the second case long term exposure can be dangerous depending on how much you're ingesting.

Comment: While this is a good answer to a bad question, can you please refrain from answering obviously off topic questions? It only encourages more of the same.